# Google maps get indoor building lat lng

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-indoor-maps

Is there a way to get the lat lng of currently focused indoor building?

There is a callback onIndoorBuildingFocused() which gets called when an indoor building gets focused. It is possible to get that building using

```
IndoorBuilding building = mMap.getFocusedBuilding();
```

But how can the lat lng of the this building be found ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [getCameraPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getCameraPosition()) and then call the [target](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html#target) of the CameraPosition object to find out the current focused location.